# call function when button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to call the action() only when the button is clicked. 
but its not happening :/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

         var window = $("#space"),
             undo = $("#button");

         undo.bind("click", function() { action(); });

         var onClose = function() { undo.show(); };

         if (!window.data("kendoWindow")) {

              window.kendoWindow({
                  width: "600px",
                  title: "Basic Reports ",
                  close: onClose
              });
         }
});
```

Comment: Show relevant HTML too

Comment: where is action declared?

Comment: From the jQuery documentation: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: Isn't 'window' a reserved keyword?? var window = $("#space") seems pretty dangerous to me.

Comment: @frenchie  not really but good catch:  http://jsfiddle.net/yBaZA/  Here OP is using a local variable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fY8xw/2/ tells me that it should work anyways. sorry for the question but did you load jQuery properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply attach the **action** function as the event handler like so:

```
$('#button').click(action);
```

Comment: That's true in a general sense, but if the code shown in the question doesn't work why would that work?

Comment: action() is loading on page load. i only want to show action() on button click

Comment: @ShauzabAliRawjani You should show us your complete code because this doesn't add up.

Answer (score 1):

You can use on instead of bind:

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    action();
});
```

From the jQuery API documentation:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

Comment: maybe the button element does not exist at the point when the bind call occurs

Comment: OK, in that case how does the code you've shown help? It is equivalent to `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
undo.bind("click", action);
```

You can do that this way.

Comment: Of course not do that!  undo.bind("click", action); this way yes

Comment: Why would this work if the code shown in the question doesn't work?

Comment: @nnnnnn did you actually test if the code doesn't work? Because to me it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3SjeS/

Comment: @zsawyer - Your fiddle proves my point, which is that if this code works the code shown in the question should also work. (Yes, I understand about the difference in `this`, and the event object passed to the handler, but the question doesn't mention either of those, so...) I think there's something else going on in code that the OP hasn't shown.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery so simply use

```
$("#Your_button_id").click(function(){
    // place your coding here
});
```

Comment: Did you read the code shown in the question? Why doesn't it work as is?